# How to apply imported module to active object

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to import a module (I think that's the right term) and then run it on the active object

In the console I can type:

```
> from bl_operators.uvcalc_smart_project import main
> main(C, .02, 30, 0.03, True, True)
```

... and it does smartuvproject on the active object.

In my script I have:

```
from bl_operators.uvcalc_smart_project import main
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
main(C, .02, 30, 0.03, True, True)
```

... and the console says that "name C is not defined"

I realise I'm missing something pretty basic here, to do with how a function is applied to an object in Blender scripts.

Perhaps the answer is, "go away and learn python." But this stuff is so Blender-specific (maybe even Blender 2.80 specific) that I'm not sure I'm going to find the answer anywhere except here!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Py console convenience variables**

C and D are abbreviated named variables for our convenience in the python console (see startup message)

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55)  [GCC 8.2.0]

Command History:     Up/Down Arrow
Cursor:              Left/Right Home/End
Remove:              Backspace/Delete
Execute:             Enter
Autocomplete:        Ctrl-Space
Zoom:                Ctrl +/-, Ctrl-Wheel
Builtin Modules:     bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports: from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data
```

Simply replace `C` with `bpy.context` in your script

**On importing**

you are importing the method `main` from the module `bl_operators.uvcalc_smart_project1` similarly

```
from bl_operators import uvcalc_smart_project

uvcalc_smart_project.main(...)
```

for keeping one main method distinct from another main method imported from elsewhere by using module as a namespace.

IMO something like

```
from bl_operators.uvcalc_smart_project import main as uv_smart_project
# and use via
uv_smart_project(...)
```

is distinct and readable.

Comment: "distinct and readable" is right. That's very neat. Thanks as ever batFINGER - your help is greatly appreciated.